# Create Django Model Object Instance Without DB Lookup For Foreign Keys

Tags: django, django-models

I have a use case where I want to be able to create instances of model objects that have foreign key constraints to other models.

`models.py`

```
from django.db import models

class Foo(models.Model):

    __module__ = "some_app"
    foo_name = models.CharField(null=False, blank=False,
                                unique=True, max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.foo_name


class Bar(models.Model):

    __module__ = "some_app"
    bar_name = models.CharField(null=False, blank=False,
                            unique=True, max_length=50)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.bar_name

class FooBar(models.Model):

     __module__ = "some_app"
     version = models.IntegerField(null=False, blank=False)
     foo = models.ForeignKey(Foo, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
     bar = models.ForeignKey(Bar, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.foo}@{self.bar}: {self.version}"
```

Say for example I have instances of my `Foo` and `Bar` classes.

```
a_foo = Foo(foo_name="my_foo")
a_foo.save()

a_bar = Bar(bar_name="my_bar")
a_bar.save()
```

Some time after they've been created, I know what the names are, but I don't have references to the objects. Similarly I don't know their ids. But I do want to use them to create an instance of `FooBar`. I can create that instance by doing this

```
foo = get_object_or_404(Foo, foo_name="my_foo")
bar = get_object_or_404(Bar, bar_name="my_bar")
foo_bar = FooBar(foo=foo, bar=bar, version=1)
```

But would like to avoid having to make two unnecessary DB calls to create, instances of the objects. Or even just to look up their ids. What I'd prefer to do is something like this

```
foo_bar = FooBar(foo__foo_name="my_foo", bar__bar_name="my_bar", version=1)
```

Then have the DB return an error if the corresponding objects don't exist (or aren't unique). Is there a way to this?

Comment: There's no possible way to do this. A ForeignKey is linked by the ID of the related model, by definition; so at some point you do actually have to get that ID.

Comment: You can absolutely do it by passing in the for the id for the reference object, in which case Django does a look up on server side. In principle, providing the value for a unique field on the object is exactly the same thing.  Which might actually be the answer to my question...